# Can i combine two or more different events for one method?

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I'm using `FileSystemWatcher`.

It's easy when combining events with same type,  here (`FileSystemEventArgs`), and i saw about passing extra parameters to an event Handler, but passing an event to an Event Method, i don't know how.

Before, i want to do something like this:

```
private void SystemWatch(object sender, 
                         System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e, 
                         System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs f)
```

But we can't change the `FileSystemEventHandler` or `RenamedEventHandler` delegate, so is there any alternative way ?

Comment: Wait ... what?  RenamedEventArgs *inherits* FileSystemEventArgs.  Why would you ever need both.

Comment: Why do you want all the events to go through the one handler? Don't you then have to introduce logic within the handler to separate out the events again?

Answer (score 2):

Delegates, like those found in events, define the method signature expected to be called. As such, events with differing signatures cannot implicitly call a method with a differing signature.

One potential workaround might be to use a dynamic lambda method to perform the translation:

```
watcher.Created += (s, a) => SystemWatch(s, null, a);
watcher.Renamed += (s, a) => SystemWatch(s, a, null);
```

*EDIT:*

After further consideration, as McGarnagle stated, `RenamedEventsArgs` inherits from `FileSystemEventArgs`. You should be able to handle both scenarios using a single event handler:

```
private static void OnCreatedOrRenamed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
```

You can tell which operation it is by checking the type of `e`:

```
if (e is RenamedEventArgs)
    ...
else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if file was created or renamed with basic `Changed` event handler:

```
watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
```

It has argument of `FileSystemEventArgs` type, which provides information of change type:

```
void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ChangeType)
    {
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:            
            break; // file was created
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed:
            break; // file was renamed
    }
}
```